# Hide title and action bar for splash screen and remove White screen in start

Tags: android

I want to remove title and ActionBar on top of my splash activity. I tried the below code,

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSplashThread.start();
```

but its not working
anyone can help , why this does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way
//add to AndroidManifest for SplashScreen
<activity
         android:name="<YOUR_PACKAGENAME.ACTIVITY>"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
         .........../>
//add this styles to  styles.xml

 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

//add this code to Activity
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
.
.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    .
    .
    .
    }

}
```

Comment: its hiding navigation item color to transparent what  to do..@sirmagid

Comment: yep change background color to #FFF